# Angular 2 execute script after template render

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

So I have this slider component that use materializecss javascript. So after it's rendered, I need to execute

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('Slider-Loaded',function(){
        console.log('EVENT SLIDER LOADED');
        $('.slider').slider({full_width: true});
        $('.slider').hover(function () {
            $(this).slider('pause');
        }, function () {
            $(this).slider('start')
        });
    });
});
```

But I don't quite knows where to put this line since typescript/angular remove script tag in templates. I've included JQuery in the ts files and was hoping to use the event system, but that doesn't seems to work. Any ideas? Here's the code of the ts file:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/main.d.ts" />
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import { RouterLink } from 'angular2/router';
import {ServerService} from './server';


@Component({
    selector: 'slider',
    templateUrl:'/app/template/slider.html',
    directives: [  ],
})

export class SliderComponent {
    @Input() images;
    private server: ServerService;
    public constructor(server: ServerService){
        this.server = server;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("THROWING EVENT");
        $('body').trigger('Slider-Loaded');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

`ngAfterViewInit()` of `AppComponent` is a lifecycle callback Angular calls after the root component and its children have been rendered and it should fit for your purpose.

See also https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Hey, would you happen to know by any chance why the even wasn't catch before. Even if the element wasn't rendered, I expected jquery to catch the event but be unable to act on .slider since it wasn't rendered.

Comment: Actually, no. I don't use jQuery myself. I also would expect `$('body').trigger(...)` to work anytime, no matter if the component is done initializing or not.

Comment: Hi, I know it's an old question but I'm having a problem trying to run jQuery code from the `ngAfterViewInit` hook. The code I want to run is:

`$('#item-panel-tabs').foundation();`
`$('#item-panel-tabs').foundation('selectTab', 'objectPanel');`

The problem is that the tab element (ID `#item-panel-tabs`) is under a `*ngIf` directive, only shown when the component receives an object, so when I call the jQuery function it's not in the DOM and it doesn't work. Any suggestion for fixing this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427769/217408 might help or you can use `[hidden]="!condition"` instead of `*ngIf="condition"` to get the element added immediately, but just not shown.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. ngAfterViewInit() is off course NOT run after template is displayed. I tried this many times and the page just starts displaying the elements, and this method runs. So it doesn't run after component has been fully displayed

Comment: @VladimirDespotovic You could post a link to a http://stackblitz.com that supports your claim

Comment: I don't know why, but my page is empty, when the ngAfterViewInit is triggered. There is literally nothing on the browsers screen when this function is triggered. So, no, it does not work like that, I don't care what Angular officials say, nor what online documentation says.

Comment: If you don't provide concrete information I can't help you. Thanks for the downvote bth.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer actually he's right, the ngAfterViewInit of AppComponent is run after AppComponent has initialized but nested components might still be waiting for init/ajax call responses..

Comment: @mare I had such a suspicion, but I don't think that is related. There can't be a lifecycle method that is run after some arbitrary async call is completed. One never knows when an async call completes. This is not an issue with Angular or my answer.

Comment: Fwiw I solved my issue by using resolver so that when component starts to render it already has the data it needs and rendering of DOM is not tied to ajax calls. This might not always be possible (depends on the use case).

Comment: ngAfterViewInit still triggers waaaay too fast

Comment: I don't think it is correct to say that ngAfterViewInit() is called after the component has been rendered.  It is called once Angular is satisfied that all aspects of the view are ready to be rendered and offers a chance to make an update before the next tick.

Answer (score 16):

Actually `ngAfterViewInit()` will initiate only once when the component initiate.

If you really want a event triggers after the HTML element renter on the screen then you can use `ngAfterViewChecked()`

Answer (score 4):

I have found that the best place is in NgAfterViewChecked(). I tried to execute code that would scroll to an ng-accordion panel when the page was loaded. I tried putting the code in NgAfterViewInit() but it did not work there (NPE). The problem was that the element had not been rendered yet. There is a problem with putting it in NgAfterViewChecked(). NgAfterViewChecked() is called several times as the page is rendered. Some calls are made before the element is rendered. This means a check for null may be required to guard the code from NPE.  I am using Angular 8.

Comment: Same experience, ngAfterViewInit was called before elements rendered and ngAfterViewChecked was being called repeatedly. I don't feel like handling this by null check is a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the function to be rendered multiple times `ngAfterContentChecked` will be preferable.

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  
  searchRegister: any = [];

  constructor() {
  }
  
  setHTMLElements() {
    this.searchRegister = ['cards-descriptor__subtitle','insights-card__title','article-headline__title','wysiwyg__content','footer-logo__heading','hero-breadcrumbs__blurb','multi-column-text__body','small-two-column-image-text__blurb','two-column-image-text__blurb','image-blurbs-expandable__desc',];
      for (var val of this.searchRegister) {
        var classLength = this.dom.body.getElementsByClassName(val).length;
        for (var i = 0; i <= classLength; i++) {
          if (
            this.dom.body.getElementsByClassName(val)[i]?.innerHTML != undefined
          ) {
            this.dom.body.getElementsByClassName(val)[
              i
            ].innerHTML = this.dom.body
              .getElementsByClassName(val)
              [i]?.innerHTML?.replace(/[®]/gi, '<sup>®</sup>');
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**Other.component.ts**

```
import { AppComponent } from '../../app.component';
export class IndustryComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private appComponent: AppComponent) { }

  ngAfterContentChecked(): void {
    this.appComponent.setHTMLElements();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I've used this method (reported [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13965#issuecomment-308795570) )

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor() {
    if(document.getElementById("testScript"))
      document.getElementById("testScript").remove();
    var testScript = document.createElement("script");
    testScript.setAttribute("id", "testScript");
    testScript.setAttribute("src", "assets/js/test.js");
    document.body.appendChild(testScript);
  }
}
```

it worked for me since I wanted to execute a javascript file AFTER THE COMPONENT RENDERED.

Comment: surprise that this method may work, because of the order of implementation. HTML comes before data institiating. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707621/template-loading-first-before-constructor-in-ionic-2-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39707621/template-loading-first-before-constructor-in-ionic-2-app)