# Angular2 calling custom function after ngSwitch new view is created

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, ionic2

I am creating a small app using **`Angular2+Ionic2`**. In this app I want initialise `google-map` into `view segment` when user switch to the `map-segment` using **`ion-segment`**

Following is the sample code structure:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar class="hide-navbar">
    <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="homeSegment">
        <ion-segment-button value="list">
            List..
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="map" >
            Map
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
</ion-navbar>
<ion-content>
    <div [ngSwitch]="homeSegment" >

        <div *ngSwitchWhen="'map'">
            <div id="googleMap"></div>
        </div>

        <ion-list *ngSwitchWhen="'list'">
           Listing
        </ion-list>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

I have tried by providing **`click`** listener for **`ion-segment-button`**, but that doesn't worked out. Before **`div`** with **`id="googleMap"`** is appended to **`DOM`**, functionality for adding map gets triggered, and which result a **`undefined error`**.

So, how we can understand when new elements are loaded when an **`ngSwitch`** happens? Whats the best way to do it?

## update (adding js code)

```
import {Page, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {DataServiceManager} from '../../services/dataServicesManager';

@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/listFob/listFob.html'
})
export class ListFob {
    static get parameters(){
        return [[NavController],[DataServiceManager]];
    }
    onPageWillEnter(){
        this.fetchFobs();
    }
    ngOnInit(){
        console.log("on init");
        console.log(this.homeSegment);
    }
    ngAfterContentChecked() {
        console.log("content checked")
    }
    constructor(nav, dataServiceManager){
        this.nav = nav;
        this.dataServiceManager = dataServiceManager;
        this.homeSegment = "list";
    }
    loadMap(){
        console.log(document.getElementById("googleMapAllFobs"));
        // TODO: load map functionality
    }
}
```

## Error message coming while adding Directive

```
./app/directives/switch-segment.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /Users/Piccaza/ionic-projects/learning/fob/app/directives/switch-segment.js: Unexpected token (8:27)
   6 | })
   7 | export class SwitchSegment {
>  8 |     @Output() switchSegment: EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
     |                            ^
   9 |     ngOnInit() {
  10 |         console.log("Directive triggered!");
  11 |         this.onCreate.emit('dummy');
    at Parser.pp.raise (/Users/Piccaza/ionic-projects/learning/fob/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1378:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/Piccaza/ionic-projects/learning/fob/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2817:8)
    at Parser.pp.expect (/Users/Piccaza/ionic-projects/learning/fob/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2811:33)
    at Parser.pp.parseMethod (/Users/Piccaza/ionic-projects/learning/fob/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1091:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseClassMethod (/Users/Piccaza/ionic-projects/learning/fob/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2495:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseClassBody (/Users/Piccaza/ionic-projects/learning/fob/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2456:10)
    at Parser.pp.parseClass (/Users/Piccaza/ionic-projects/learning/fob/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2339:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/Users/Piccaza/ionic-projects/learning/fob/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1813:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExportDeclaration (/Users/Piccaza/ionic-projects/learning/fob/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2578:15)
    at Parser.pp.parseExport (/Users/Piccaza/ionic-projects/learning/fob/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2566:29)
 @ ./app/pages/listFob/listFob.js 16:21-63 (CLI v2.0.0-beta.19)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: Not installed
Ionic Version: 2.0.0-beta.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.19
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.9
ios-deploy version: 1.8.5 
ios-sim version: 5.0.6 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v5.3.0
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2.1 Build version 7C1002
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in support of calling a function when `ngSwitch` adds/removes elements.

I would create a directive that calls the function when created (for example in `ngOnInit()`) or emits an event where an event handler can be bound to, and  apply it to the component that is added when the `ngSwitch` branch is enabled.

If `ngSwitch` adds a component you can implement it in this component as well (depends on your requirements)

**update**

```
    <ion-list (onCreate)="doSomething()" *ngSwitchCase="'list'">
       Listing
    </ion-list>
```

```
@Directive(selector: '[onCreate]')
export class OnCreate implements OnInit {
  @Output() onCreate:EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit() {
    this.onCreate.emit('dummy');
  }
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/2rZAAo?p=preview)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108403/discussion-between-dipak-chandran-p-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: I have added an answer, which seems to be resolved my problem. Thank you so much for all your input.

Comment: Thanks @jsgoupil, saw your change to late to accept it myself.

Answer (score 4):

You can also call a function when ion-segment is changed.

```
<ion-segment [(ngModel)]="homeSegment" (ionChange)="updatePage(homeSegment)">
```

and in your component a function like

```
updatePage(homeSegment) {
  if (homeSegment === 'map') {
    this.loadMap();
  }
}
```

Maybe this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Finally how I resolved this is by, by providing a **`(change)="onSegmentChanged($event)"`** on **`ion-segment element`**.

Which will trigger whenever **`ion-segment`** will `switch`. And I am able to access the `dom element with id googleMapAllFobs` when its getting switched to **`value="map"`**.

Provided a checking in **`onSegmentChanged`** function, before call `load google map` function, to ensure the current view contains div to load google map.

Looks very easy for this current requirement.

Comment: Hi, Dipak. Facing the same task, but have no idea how to get back the reference to the  DOM-element after `onSegmentChanged` occur.
Can you please share a piece of code? How do you declare and access the element before and after  `onSegmentChanged`?
Im using `@ViewChild` decorator to catch the div with a map, but it is undefined after the first event appearance as div is removed from the DOM...

Comment: Can you share how you manage to make it work .. I have tried but couldn't make it work :(