# *ngFor running an infinite loop in angular2

Tags: typescript, angular, ngfor

I am trying to render object properties using keys in angular2 using below code:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let element of componentModel | keys;let i=index">
      {{element.key}}--{{element.value}}  // 1---Bhushan...loaded only once
      <span  *ngIf="element">{{ loadProperty(i,element) }}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But I am facing a problem here. The output in the browser in loaded only once. 
but the method call i.e. `loadProperty(i,element)` is running in an infinite loop.

```
loadProperty(i:number,element:any){       
    console.log(element.key+'========'+element.value);
    console.log(element);      
}
```

means on browser output

> (1---Bhushan)

is displayed only once but on the console its running infinitely like below:

[image: Snapshot of the console]

I want to call this method only once per iteration.

any inputs?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is just Angular2 change detection at work calling `loadProperty(i,element)` over and over in each change detection cycle.

Calling methods from the template is discouraged because they are called very often. You should instead store the result in a property and bind to this property instead.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this with property binding, do u have any plnkr for this where method will get called only once per iteration? @Gunter

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Sounds like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427670/angular2-calling-custom-function-after-ngswitch-new-view-is-created/36427769#36427769

Comment: pretty much same but I also want to pass the iterated element to the method. actually these elements are objects and I am providing an editor for each element based on its type to change its value. ie. if it's an object consisting of arrays then it will load objectEditorComponent & inside that it will load arrayEditorComponent for each array. thus I use *ngFor to iterate and pass iterated element to function to select correct editor based on its datatype. its a recursive process until it gets the last element.

Comment: What part exactly is causing you troubles?

Comment: the one I mentioned in the question. the function is getting called for multiple times though I want it to get called only once per iteration

Comment: That's exactly what the directive in the linked answer is supposed to do.  `<span  *ngIf="element" (onCreate)="loadProperty(i, element)"></span>` should do what you want.

Comment: i have got this error `Generic type 'EventEmitter<T>' requires 1 type argument(s)`

Comment: That's caused by the static checks in your IDE. Just use the type you want to pass. In my example it emits `"dummy"` which would require `@Output() someOutput:EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();`