# Angular Is there any way to call promise function from template dynamically and return a text

Tags: angular, promise

I have two `servince.ts` function

```
getSessions(): Promise<UserSessionInterface[]> {
    return this.sessioAPI.find()
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response as UserSessionInterface);
}
getUserDetails(id: string): Promise<any> {
    return this.sessioAPI.getUser(id)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.firstName + ' ' + response.lastName)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

I call them on `component.ts` like this

```
getSessions() {
    this._service.getSessions()
        .then(result => {
            this.results = result;
        });
}

getUserDetails(id?: string) {
    return this._service.getUserDetails(id)
        .then(result => {
            console.log('Inside result : ' + result);
            this.userName = result;
        });
} 

getUserName(id: string) {
    return this.getUserDetails(id);
}
```

I know I can do it with single request inside of component and assign the result to global variable.

But, what I want is to call `getUserName` function dynamically inside of `*ngFor`, and return the result of Promise as string directly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a comment, since seems you are considering calling function in template, scrap that, because: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876533/ngfor-running-an-infinite-loop-in-angular2

Comment: `getUserName() | async`? But as pointed out by @AJT_82, that function will be called again on every tick. I've written a blog post on how we're handling async data you might find useful: http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html

Comment: Exactly,  the function is calling again and again on every tick.