# simple templete loop in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I just want to create a simple loop in html

such as

```
for(int i = 1; i < n ; i++){
  //do something
}
```

i found may soltion but non of them working for me here is one of them

```
<li *ngFor='#loop of counter(5) ;#i= index'>{{i}}</li>
```

can anyone help me with this

Comment: `#`  is old angular 2 beta syntax, check the tutorials: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ngfor

Comment: ... and since this is a basic question, I suggest you start off with the TOH tutorial, you'll learn the basics :) https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: one more thing, calling methods in template is a bad idea, I suggest you rethink that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876533/ngfor-running-an-infinite-loop-in-angular2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you :)

**Component**

```
counter(number){
    // do something with the number passed
    let list: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];
    return list;
  }
```

**Template**

```
<li *ngFor='let loop of counter(5);let i= index'>{{i}}</li>
```

And Better start with some tutorials [**this**](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts) might help