# simple binding in range component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to implement simple slider range value control in angular 2 app.
On stackoverflow I've found this solution

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" #ranger (input)="getMyValue()">

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  myValue: number;

  constructor() { }    

   getMyValue() {   
      this.myValue = 2;
   }

  ngOnInit() { }

}
```

this always sets control to default state (which is 50). 
When I simply use html without binding html renders control properly.

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" #ranger value = 2>
```

What I'm missing here?

Comment: What does `getMyValue` return? Hint: **not** your value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this,

```
 <input type="range"  id="range"  min="0" max="100"
    value = "{{getMyValue()}}">
```

and in TS:

```
 getMyValue() {   
      return 2;
 }
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/pxQtOjfuoQ1Tt9wt5OVd?p=preview)**

Comment: Any suggestions, links or docs on how can I track range control change in the view and obviously to update property in the angular 2 controller?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use a variable with ngModel instead. Calling methods in template means that every time Angular runs change detection, method will be called, so for example this can happen: [*ngFor running an infinite loop in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876533/ngfor-running-an-infinite-loop-in-angular2) Technically it's not an infinite loop, but method gets called over and over. Especially if you are making http-requests, your browser will crash.

So what I would do:

```
myValue: number;

ngOnInit() {
  this.myValue = 2;
}
```

Template:

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" #ranger [(ngModel)]="myValue">
```

Comment: Thanks, how can I track the changes of the slider and change the value of myValue variable?

Comment: It's two-way binding, so you always have the current value in `myValue` in your component :)