# angular sort by on ngfor

Tags: angular, sorting

I have the following ngFor statement and I want to sort by price.
https://plnkr.co/edit/DC8I8DRB5UKhvWf6Sppl?p=preview

```
<div *ngFor="let coin of keys(); let i = index;">{{feeds[coin].price}}</div>

export class PricingTableComponent{

  public feeds:  FeedItemDictionary = {};

  constructor(service: PricingApiService,private route:ActivatedRoute) {   

      this.feeds["btc"] = {price : 1,coin : "BitCoin"} ;
      this.feeds["eth"] = {price : 2,coin : "Etherium"} ;
      //... 1300 like this...
    });
  }

  keys() {
    return Object.keys(this.feeds);
  }
}

interface FeedItemDictionary {
  [ index: string ]: FeedItem // price and coin memebers
}
```

the problem is that this is a dictionary (I must use a dictionary or map).
Is it possible to sort by value member?
Can you please fix my example in plnkr?
Thanks

Comment: So what do you want to sort on? The key, or the price, or the `coin` string?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I wouldn't call a method in the template, why? This means that this method will be called on each change detection, which is often: [*ngFor running an infinite loop in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37876533/ngfor-running-an-infinite-loop-in-angular2) In worst case this can crash your browser.

You could use a pipe to order, but I wouldn't use that, also mention in the docs why there isn't an inbuilt order or filter pipe: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

What I would do, is handle all the business logic in the component, and then just iterate an array in template. So I'd first make your data iterable as well as sorting it:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  let keyArr: any[] = Object.keys(this.feeds)
  keyArr.forEach((key: any) => {
    // push object with abbreviation, price and coin to array
    this.myArray.push({ abbrv: key, price: this.feeds[key].price, coin: this.feeds[key].coin });
  });
  // ASC
  this.myArray = this.myArray.sort((a, b) => a.price - b.price)
}
```

With this you end up with an array like:

```ts
[{abbrv: "eth", price: 54115, coin: "Etherium"}, ....]
```

and in your template you would just then iterate `myArray`:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of myArray">
  {{item.abbrv}} = {{item.price}}
</div>
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-32yvuj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thank you.
The thing is, the array is actually lined with a socket, and evey 0.05 second there is a change in the array. So, in your way. is it going to work for me?
Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To sort by the `coin` string, change your `keys` function to the following:

```
keys()  {
   return Object
     .keys(this.feeds)
     .sort((a, b) => this.feeds[a].coin.localeCompare(this.feeds[b].coin));
}
```

If, however, you want to sort by the value of `price` (ascending), then change it to the following:

```
keys()  {
   return Object
     .keys(this.feeds)
     .sort((a, b) => this.feeds[a].price - this.feeds[b].price));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a pipe:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'SortBy'
})
export class IeSortPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(values: Array<string>, args?: string): any {

  if(args==='ASC')
    values = values.sort();
    else
    values = values.sort().reverse();

    return values;
  }
}
```

I added to your code the sort pipe:

https://plnkr.co/edit/L6Wk2GlsRb53RsNUeurx?p=preview