# Angular *ngFor Does not load images and enters an infinite loop

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function that loads product data from a database.
This data will be loaded into html using * ngFor.

After uploading the data, I intend to upload the image for this product ID. That is, I try to pass the product ID and I have perform the function of getting images, with id I get.

The problem is that * ngFor goes into a continuous loop and neither images load :(

The problem will be in this line, because if the comment code runs without any infinite loop. (of course not upload images):

```
<img *ngIf="inView" [src]="ImageInfo(product.id)"  class="Images img-fluid" alt="" (click)="fillModal($event)">
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid first" style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalPoll">
      <div class="row tab-pane Galeria">
        <div *ngFor="let product of products" class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
          <div class="image-item">
            <homeImage>
              <a class="d-block image-block h-100">
                <img *ngIf="inView" [src]="ImageInfo(product.id)"  class="Images img-fluid" alt="" (click)="fillModal($event)"> 
              </a>
            </homeImage>
            <div class="ImageText"> {{product.name}}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could please post your component class?

Comment: @RafiHenig 
I put in the post the link of my code (stackblitz), there you find everything I'm using

Comment: You should completely restructure your code and fetch all the products and image for all products before showing in template: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37876533/6294072

Comment: @AJT82
I think this is the problem. I only use the homeImage model to load the images as I scroll .... I can't solve the problem :(

Comment: Please edit your stackblitz link

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it a try. It might not be the answer but if I'm not mistaken you have a flaw in your img source: `[src]="ImageInfo(product.id)"`.

Here your code doesn't return anything:

```
ImageInfo(id) {
      var self = this;
      self.Global.refreshToken().subscribe(function (result) {
        self.homeService.getImage(id).then(function (resultado) {
          if (resultado) {
             self.Imagenss = resultado;
          }
        }).catch();
      });
    }
```

So there's no source. You're just assisgning the "imagenss" variable the result of your request.

I can't test it but you might need to do something like:

```
ImageInfo(id) {
      var self = this;
      self.Global.refreshToken().subscribe(function (result) {
        self.homeService.getImage(id).then(function (resultado) {
          if (resultado) {
             self.Imagenss = resultado;
             return self.Imagenss; // <---- HERE RETURNING WHAT I ASSUME TO BE THE PATH
          }
        }).catch();
      });
    }
```

Comment: I had already tested this and it didn't work, it's still in an endless loop of service requests :(

Answer (score 0):

Structurally some things need to be re-ordered. Try fetching all the data you need from the API in your ngOnInit():

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.GetProducts();
  this.GetAllImageInformation();
}
```

The culprit line that probably hangs is this one:

```
<img *ngIf="inView" [src]="ImageInfo(product.id)" class="Images img-fluid" alt="">
```

By calling a function inside [src], this function will execute whenever data is updated. Since the backend triggers a data refresh, it will then call the function again etc. etc.

Try structure your code in a way to first fetch all your data and try to pass a **string** with the location of the image to [src]. This will most likely solve your problem.

Comment: Continues to infinity loop requests to service in function to get image :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is better to change your approach to get images. Instead of getting them in `ngFor`, it is better to get all images on initialization and populate them in your template:

```
allImagesLoaded = false; // variable to show whether images are loaded
getImages(productIds) {
    // your aPI method that returns images. Result depends on your server i.e. base64 data, image url

    this.allImagesLoaded = true; 
}
```

and then render all your images:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="allImagesLoaded ">
    <div *ngFor="let product of products" class="col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
      <div class="image-item">
        <homeImage>
          <a class="d-block image-block h-100">
            <img *ngIf="inView" [src]="ImageInfo(product.id)"  
                class="Images img-fluid" alt="" 
                (click)="fillModal($event)"> 
          </a>
        </homeImage>
        <div class="ImageText"> {{product.name}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
 <ng-container>
```

or if your count of images not so many, then you can include your images into your project and use it in `img` tag:

```
<img [src]="imagePath" />
```

Comment: I got: context error on this line <ng-container * ngIf = "allImagesLoaded">

Comment: @Harry you should create a API method that returns images and then apply the  above code

Comment: I have this method created in the service and it is working. I may have misapplied your code too :(

Comment: I updated the stackblitz link because I had not placed the homeImage component ... I may have problem because of this :(