# remove ngIf attribute after it is evaluated as true

Tags: angular

Is there a way how to remove ngIf attribute after it has been evalauated as true?

example , lets say i have a template

```
<div class="container">
   <div *ngFor="let el of elements">
        <div *ngIf="el.index = index">
         ...
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

and in component i have counter

```
class Test implements onInit{
   index = 0;

   ngOnInit(){
     setInterval( () => index++ )
   }
}
```

this would mean that only one div at time would be displayed , however i want all divs that has been previously displayed to stay displayed in other words, remove ngIf property once it was evaluated as true.

Is something like that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. You should rather maintain the list of elements in your component to contain what `*ngFor` should render.

Comment: Is it atleast possible to evaluate function when ngIf resolves as true?

Comment: You could use a directive like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427670/angular2-calling-custom-function-after-ngswitch-new-view-is-created/36427769#36427769 but your requirement looks more like working against Angular2 rather than with it (except maybe you are using jQuery widgets)

Comment: i resolved it by passing function that check if isViewed attribute is true if so automaticly returns true. If not it check condition , if condition is true it set isViewed as true

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own ngIf :

```
@Directive( { selector : '[myNgIf]' } )
export class myNgIfDirective {
    private condition;

    constructor ( private templateRef : TemplateRef<any> ,
                  private viewContainer : ViewContainerRef ) {
    }

    @Input() set myNgIf ( condition : boolean ) {
        if ( this.condition !== true ) {
        // if this condition is once set to true , don't bother doing anything anymore 
            this.condition = condition;
            if ( condition ) {
                this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView( this.templateRef );
            } else {
                this.viewContainer.clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it:

```
 <div *myNgIf ="isTrue">stuff</div>
```