# Ionic 2 custom funstions for Maps to be used in Segments

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to create an App using ionic 2. I want to create 2 segments with Maps and list. Tried to follow below link

[Angular2 calling custom function after ngSwitch new view is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36427670/angular2-calling-custom-function-after-ngswitch-new-view-is-created)

But never got it to be worked. I think my .scss file is not able to recognize the ID that was created in the html file. Below is my html code:

```
 <ion-segment [(ngModel)]="clients" >
      <ion-segment-button value="map">
        Map
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="list">
        List
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
      </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content >
  <div [ngSwitch]="clients">
  <div *ngSwitchCase="'map'">
    <div class="map" >
        <div #map id="map"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'list'">
      <ion-item>
        <h2>Item 1</h2>
      </ion-item>    
     </ion-list>

  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the class name in your .scss file to the ion-content tag.

For example, in your .scss file if the base class is home, add that class in ion-content in the html code as follows:

```
<ion-content class="home">
```

Comment: This is my .scss file.

  #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }

With the above html and .scss files maps or list doesn't load at all. But if i put <div #map id="map"></div> after <ion-content> tag maps load. In this case map and list segment both load Maps. But i want list items to be loaded in List segment.