# Template loading first before constructor in Ionic 2 App

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am working on an ionic 2 app. I'm trying to invoke a service in my component and try to access it in the template. But the issue I'm facing is that the template is loading first and then the promise output in my component is succeeding. So I get undefined error from the template if I try to access any 'req_obj' values. How do I make sure that the promise gets resolved first and then my template waits to get the output?

My service:

```
loadTruckdetail(id)
{
if (this.truckListdetail) {
  return Promise.resolve(this.truckListdetail);
}

return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get('http://demo.truckjee.com/api/trucks/' + id + '?api_token='+this.userToken)
    .map(res => {
      return res.json().truck;
    })
    .subscribe(truck => {
      this.truckListdetail = truck;
      resolve(this.truckListdetail);
      console.log(this.truckListdetail);
      console.log(this.truckListdetail.id);
    });
});
}
```

My component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ionicBootstrap, Platform, Nav } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { NavController, NavParams, LoadingController  } from 'ionic-angular';
import {Dashboardparam} from '../../providers/user-data/user-data';
import {Api} from '../../providers/api/api';
import {Authentication} from '../../providers/authentication/authentication';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/requirement-show/requirement-show.html',
  providers: [Api]
})
@Injectable()
export class RequirementShowPage {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  req_obj: any;
  my_trucks: any;
  bids: any;
  cargo_details: any;
  payment_details: any;
  is_valid: number;

constructor(private builder: FormBuilder, private Auth: Authentication, public nav: NavController, private api: Api, navParams: NavParams, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
  api.loadDetail(navParams.get('id'))
  .then( requirementValue => {
    this.req_obj = requirementValue;
console.log(req_obj);
  });
}
}
```

JSON response from the api:

```
{"message":"success","requirement":{"id":42,"status":0,"no_of_trucks":1,"user_id":11,"source":"Vadakkencherry, Kerala 678683, India","source_locality":"Vadakkencherry","source_district":"Palakkad","source_state":"Kerala","destination":"Chennai, Tamil Nadu, India","destination_locality":"Chennai","destination_district":"Chennai","destination_state":"Tamil Nadu","date_required":"Sep 26, 2016","date_delivery":"Sep 26, 2016","transit_time":1,"cargo_details":{},"payment_details":{},"valid_till":"2016-09-26 22:28:59","created_at":"2016-09-26 16:28:59","updated_at":"2016-09-26 16:28:59","expected_cost":"22500","created_by":11,"truck_types":[{"id":45,"requirement_id":42,"model_id":36,"created_at":"2016-09-26 16:28:59","updated_at":"2016-09-26 16:28:59"}],"bids":[]},"trucks":[{"id":6,"truck_id":"TR106","truck_number":"TN-52-J-9330","owner_id":7,"model_id":36,"description_id":269,"status":"0","short_form":"TN52 J9330","imei":"0358511020724179","current_locality":"Panniyankara","current_district":"Palakkad","current_state":"Kerala","current_lat":"10.5895666666666","current_long":"76.4524366666666","gps_updated_location":"NH544, Panniyankara, Kerala 678686, India","gps_last_updated":"2016-09-26 21:10:29","gps_updated_speed":"0","rc":"","insurance":"","pollution":"","np":"","authorization":"","created_at":"2016-06-03 18:34:03","created_by":1}]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `*ngIf` directive to "protect" your template, for example:

```
<div *ngIf="req_obj">
    {{req_obj.message}}
</div>
```

This way, `div` will be displayed only after value is assigned to `req_obj`. While it's value is `undefined`, there will be a comment inside your template, something like this:

```
<!--
    template bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-if": null }
-->
```