# Typescript: document.getElementById() returns null even if element is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have a function named "blockButtons" which I call inside the ngOnInit that asks for an element with a given id, but I keep getting null. Why is this happening? Isn`t ngOnInit called after all elements are loaded?

Here is my code:
HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="conference">
 <h2 class="text-danger">Sessions:</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" routerLink="/addSession/{{conference.id}}" routerLinkActive="active" id="addSessions">Add Sessions</button>
  <app-scmember-session-list [conferenceId]=conference.id></app-scmember-session-list>

  <h2 class="text-danger">PcMembers:</h2>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="addPcMembers" routerLink="/addPcMembers/{{conference.id}}" routerLinkActive="active" >Add PcMembers</button>
  <app-scmember-pcmembers-list [conferenceId]=conference.id></app-scmember-pcmembers-list>

  <br>
  <button (click)="goBack()">Back</button>
  <button (click)="save()">Save</button>
</div>
```

Typescript:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-scmember-conference-detail',
  templateUrl: './scmember-conference-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./scmember-conference-detail.component.css']
})
export class ScmemberConferenceDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() conference: Conference;

  constructor(private conferenceService: ConferenceService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private location: Location) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .subscribe((params: Params) => this.conferenceService.getConference(+params['id'])
      .subscribe(conference => {
        this.conference = conference;
        this.blockButtons();
      }));
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

  save(): void {
    this.conferenceService.update(this.conference)
      .subscribe(_ => this.goBack());
  }

  private blockButtons() {
    if(Date.now() > Date.parse(this.conference.callForPapers)){
      (<HTMLButtonElement> document.getElementById("addPcMembers")).disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You could try: [`ngAfterContentInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentInit)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 execute script after template render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36184458/angular-2-execute-script-after-template-render)

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn  I have triet both ngAfterContentInit and ngAfterViewInit but it seems they are both called before the ngOnInit, so it didn`t solve my problem

Comment: They shouldn't, according to the [Lifecycle sequence](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence).

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn yeah, my mystake. I tried now once again and it worked with ngAfterViewInit. In onInit I was instantiating the field ```this.conference```, and i tried using it in the ngAfterViewInit and it said it is null. But i instantiated it again there and then everything worked great. Thank you!